# Query fails due to `safe update mode`

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `number_locks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timeout` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `number` (`number`),
  KEY `timeout` (`timeout`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=69146 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now I would like to run this prepared delete statement in it:

```
> SET @number="123123";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)  

> PREPARE delete_number_lock FROM 'DELETE FROM number_locks WHERE number=? OR timeout<NOW()';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)
Statement prepared  

> EXECUTE delete_number_lock USING @number;
ERROR 1175 (HY000): You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column
```

I can't see why it thinks that there is no where condition using a KEY column.

Comment: I think you have asked for the reason not the way to circumvent the problem. So if you have specified that than I would have surely tried to answer it another way. I think my answer as appropriate for the question you have asked or I have misunderstood something any ways.....good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the quickest way to circumvent that is by adding a condition using the primary key that will always be true, like so:

```
DELETE 
FROM number_locks 
WHERE id > 0 AND (number=? OR timeout<NOW())
;
```

Comment: @mauro.stettler yeah, it is a little cludgy, but the only time I usually need to use it is in developement/maintenance scenarios. I was under the impressing the main purpose of SAFE UPDATES was to prevent accidents with fast hands hitting enter before the WHERE clause is entered; in that perspective requiring a keyed field seems like overkill, so it would perhaps be an attempt to limit users to executing "fast updates" only. Maybe?

Answer (score 1):

By default mysql runs in a safe update mode which helps users causing any accidental modification in the database. As you can see in the [MYSQL REFERENCE MANUAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tips.html) which says

> It is helpful for cases when you might have issued a DELETE FROM tbl_name statement but forgotten the WHERE clause. Normally, such a statement deletes all rows from the table. With --safe-updates, you can delete rows only by specifying the key values that identify them. This helps prevent accidents.

Safe mode also reject the statements where the where clause does not use a key column or constraint as the manual further says

> You are not permitted to execute an UPDATE or DELETE statement unless you specify a key constraint in the WHERE clause or provide a LIMIT clause (or both)

In your case the delete query does not uses a key constraint hence it is not executed.

So to disable safe mode try this:

`SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;`

---

**MORE UPDATE**

See your query `DELETE FROM number_locks WHERE number=? OR timeout<NOW()`

Here the column `number` is not a key column, hence the error. In case if you use `id` instead of `number` than such error would not occur because `id` is the primary key.

---

**Even More Update**

`OR` separates your `WHERE` clause into two logical parts. Let me explain you `number="12345" OR timeout<NOW()` becomes (number || timeout) which is not a key. But the condition using `AND` will works because it takes both the column collectively into the consideration. Also it is interesting to note that `OR` will work if you use same column name for example `number="12345" OR number='564789'`

Comment: Thx for the explanation. I'm not sure if I just don't understand the terminology, but is the `WHERE number=? OR timeout<NOW()` not a key constraint?

Comment: So "key column" actually means "primary key column"?

Comment: Actually `number` has a key on the column, and for example this query runs fine: `delete from number_locks where number="123";`

Comment: @mauro.stettler Yeah but not limited to primary key. It can also be a unique key or any candidate key which can be used for identification. But yeah mostly it implies to primary key.

Comment: Interestingly, even after adding a key with `alter table number_locks add unique key number_timeout (number, timeout);` it still gives me the same error. Explain confirms that it does use the key.

Comment: Just give sometime i am working out its is interesting.

Comment: @mauro.stettler it is probably the `OR` you are using, a `number, timeout` key cannot work as a key for `timeout` alone (which is most likely how it ends up being handled due to the `OR`)

Comment: @Uueerdo I agree with you I found out the same but just looking for credible information on the same.